# How to develop application for OpenStack

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, openstack

I have installed OpenStack and everywhere I see tutorials about installing and deploying but no example about `how to develop a simple app on OpenStack?` using PHP

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the services in your OpenStack cloud, I recommend reading the [php-opencloud OpenStack Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/docs/getting-started-openstack.md).

Comment: From a comment on another answer, apparently this answered it for the asker, so upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Umair --

Here is some code to get you started [Note; It uses zend framework 2]

[Opencloud skeleton app in PHP](https://github.com/jamiehannaford/zf2-opencloud-skeleton-app)

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have found PHP-OpenCloud and I have started working on it! Thanks again!